# ReCaptcha check is not working

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm currently trying to understand how ReCaptcha works.
I made this simple html form for demonstration purposes:

```
<form id="comment_form" action="form.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="email"><br><br>
  <textarea  name="comment"  rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment"><br><br>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfXcggUAAAAAJ7txEVLU949P4SHWk5eXoSYksQ1"></div>
</form>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
$email;
$comment;
$captcha;
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
}
if(isset($_POST['comment']))
{
    $email=$_POST['comment'];
}
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
{
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
if(empty($captcha))
{
    echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
    exit;
}
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=DONTPUBLUSHYOURSECRETDUDE&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($response->success === false)
{
    die('<h2>You are a spammer</h2>');
}
echo '<h2>Thanks for posting your comment.</h2>';
```

This script outputs `Thanks for posting your comment` even tho the user has not passed ReCaptcha's challenge.

Comment: @timyRS Can you please give me an example how to implement with javaScript . I have found  "g-recaptcha-response" can be use , but I did not understood  how its works on this content .

Comment: You have published your secret key, would recommend that you change it.

Comment: Yes, it was just for demonstration purpose. And thanks for the answer i am going to try it tomorrow at the school.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    $email;$comment;$captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $email=$_POST['email'];
    }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
      $email=$_POST['comment'];
    }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LfXcggUAAAAAP887f6E0W4fZF6mnp1C1lBpAUwv&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);
    if($responseKeys["success"] !== 1)
    {
      echo '<h2>You are spammer !</h2>';
    }else
    {
      echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `json_decode` the response.

And I fixed your code.

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST["email"])
|| empty($_POST["comment"])
|| empty($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) )
{
    die("Please fill out everything.");
}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$captcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=XXX&response=".$captcha), true);
if($response["success"] !== true)
{
    die("You did not pass the captcha");
}
echo "You passed the captcha. :D";
```